# Windows CMD - How to pass two commands in Start

Tags: cmd

I want to open a new command prompt and ping on that one and then pause the new screen so that it does not go away.

I used the following two command and it is not behaving as I expected.

```
start "mytitle" ping google.com pause
start "mytitle" ping google.com & pause
```

The started screen goes away and the pause command in run in the first prompt.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can run `cmd /k ping google.com`. It opens a Command Prompt (`cmd`) and tells it to run `ping google.com` and **do not exit** after `ping` completes (`/k`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On using the command line

```
start "mytitle" ping google.com & pause
```

the Windows command interpreter reads it like writing:

```
start "mytitle" ping google.com
pause
```

So first **START** is executed to run `ping` in a separate command process and while `ping` is running parallel the current command process continues with waiting for an input from handle **STDIN**. The ampersand on command line not found within a double quoted argument string is interpreted as additional command to execute after executing **START** in current command process.

You have to use:

```
start "mytitle" cmd /C "ping google.com & pause"
```

Or with full qualified file names:

```
start "mytitle" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe google.com & pause"
```

The internal command **START** of `cmd.exe` is designed for running one application. It is not designed to run a command line with one or more commands like Windows command interpreter itself.

Now a separate command process is started with `cmd.exe` which should close automatically because of option `/C` after finishing the execution of the command line specified in double quotes as second argument for started `cmd.exe` containing the instructions to execute `ping.exe` and then pause.